419 error on livewire POST request on Laravel based webiste using JMeter
I am making a testing script in JMeter in order to load test a Larvel and Livewire website. And there is a 419 error on livewire Post request when running the script.
While investigating the topic, I found out that 419 error is related to CSRF token correlation. So I've tried to extract a token value from previous GET request using Regular Expression Extractor on it from hidden input, like so:
Screen 1
Screen 2
. And I've replaced the hardcoded token value with ${token} variable from the livewire POST request:
Screen 3
. But I am still getting 419 on that request.


Use View Results Tree listener to check whether your ${token} variable contains the anticipated value
Don't forget to add a HTTP Cookie Manager to your test plan
Using regular expressions for parsing HTML is not the best idea, going forward consider using CSS Selector Extractor instead


Thank you for your response! It seems that the token variable contains the correct value. What's more, other POST request (from the same script) works fine with it, in that case the token is passed via HTTP Header (unlike the request mentioned in the problem). And i have HTTP Cookie Manager in my test plan.
